# Merge 2 views in Drupal - using filters?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a view for news items and one for events. I want to create a list that lists both of them together. However, I want to filter the news items on a custom date expires field (that events doesn't have) and I want to filter the events on a custom event date field (that news doesn't have).

Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create more complex filters using the [Views OR](http://drupal.org/project/views_or) module. It's still under development but I have used it once with good results.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. That looks like it may well answer my query.